# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужно вы отделять запятыми оборот "как он есть" в случаях, вроде "Бхагаватгита(,) как она есть"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знак перед оборотом "как он есть" не нужен.